# Progressive Web Application Can a Service Worker find out on which device it is running (Smartphone, Tablet, ...)?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I plan to create a PWA for a company. Is it possible to find out on which kind of device the PWA is running?

Comment: What would you have your SW do with the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with restrictions. This tool you can use for this:
http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/